# Is there a real difference between "wait" and "await"?

Tags: verbs, differences

In the context of the discussion in the blog post [Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 part two: Whence await?](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017040918/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) and comments on using `await` as a keyword for a potentially asynchronous operation in C#5, I wondered if there is any real difference between *await* and *wait*? Already as a dictionary definition, but also in common usage.

Comment: There's at least a trivial difference in syntax: you *wait for* X, but you *await* X.

Answer (score 12):

To await is to wait for, but at least to my mind "await" carries a stronger connotation of *expectation* than "wait". I can wait for the bus, but I eagerly await your response. Etymonline indicates that both were originally an active, hostile sort of waiting, and it seems to me that "await" has retained more of this meaning.